# How do you get the JSON request while sending a transaction on Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

While sending a transaction on testing a smart contract in Remix IDE, I am getting this error:

```
transact to Escrow.deposit errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 47
```

Comment: It would help if you pasted the parameters you're using. As a rough guess, maybe you're missing quotes around a hexadecimal number.

Comment: @smarx Thank You. It was the issue. You were right. The Remix IDE was expecting us to put the address in quotes.